# Disabled binding not working for checkboxes generated with *ngFor

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng

I have a list of objects that I want to bind to for checkboxes. The problem I'm having is that all of my checkboxes will be disabled when I only want to disable specific ones in the list. What is the proper way to setup the *ngfor and checkbox? Here I'm using the [PrimeNg checkbox](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) but if you know for a regular checkbox that would be a helpful stepping stone.

component.ts has this:

```
 this.options = [
            { name: "A", checked: true, disabled: true },
            { name: "B", checked: false, disabled: false },
            { name: "C", checked: false, disabled: false },
        ];
```

component.html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <span *ngFor="let test of options; let i=index" class="col-sm-4">
        <p-checkbox binary="true" [(ngModel)]="test.checked" label="{{test.name}}"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" disabled="{{test.disabled}}"></p-checkbox>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Bad tagging, please correct it and mention the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change how you set disabled

```
// this will always set a disabled attribute. Problem is, as soon as the attribute exists,
//  the browser disables the input. As a result, all your inputs are disabled
disabled="{{test.disabled}}"

// this binds to the DOM property, not the element attribute. When the property is false
// the browser removes the attribute from the DOM and the input is enabled
[disabled]="test.disabled"
```